# What is a "Missing file from filelist 'install-info'" warning for?

Tags: dpkg

Why when I install some packages using apt, I receive a message like this:

```
dpkg: aviso: falta ficheiro de lista de ficheiros 'install-info'; assumindo que o pacote não tem actualmente ficheiros instalados
```

Translating to

```
dpkg: Warning: Missing file from filelist 'install-info'; assuming that package has not installed files
```

It's not critical, because I can install something, but... Why this message?

Comment: Just a note, you can directly get English outputs from your commands when you write `LANG=C in front of them, like `LANG=C sudo apt install something`. But unfortunately I don't know how to help you with your described issue.